# Drupal 7 with Views 7.x-3.5, some fields not showing for Sort

Tags: drupal-7, view

I am trying to sort a view by a node field (product weight - which is a decimal), however, that field and various others do not show as fields which I can sort on.

I am hoping there is some simple fix for this, but I have been unable to find the solution.

Why do some fields show in the sort criteria, but others do not? What do I have to do to make it possible to sort by the missing fields?

Answer (score 2):

Worked it out.

You have to add an index to the search API...

Once this has been done with the appropriate fields added they should become available to sort.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-valued fields don't shows up as sortable in Drupal 7 views.
Go to your field settings->Select no of Values as 1 ->Go to view's format settings and see if Sort option s available->Check Sort->Save the view.